# Have lost my R.Java folder

Tags: android, xml

I am aware that the R.Java or the resources folder can disappear due to problems with the XML layout file. I did make a few changes to this file but made sure I had cleaned the project well, etc. However I still have the "error parsing XML junk after document element" error. Her is my code for the XML file below. Can anyone help me resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main_title" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:inputType="number" />
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/check" />
    <Button        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:onClick="checkNumbers"
        android:text="@string/button_check" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is this Your only one xml? Have You checked that all strings in strings.xml are correct?

Comment: Typically the first step is to use an XML validator to make sure your XML is valid.  Have you done that? (_obviously the answer is no_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is not valid.

There are two ways to *close* an XML tag:

**Method 1:**

```
<foo>blah blah blah</foo>
```

**Method 2:**

```
<foo value="blah blah blah"/>
```

You must use one **OR** the other (not both).

In your code you attempt to use both:

```
<LinearLayout foo="bar" baz="blah"/>   <!-- do not close the element like this -->
   <OtherStuff>blah</OtherStuff>       <!-- if you plan to do this -->
</LinerarLayout>                       <!-- or if you want to do this -->
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  You should get in the habit of using an XML validator when you run into issues like this.  It's a lot faster than asking a question on StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: thanks for the advice i will in future. to be honest i wasnt aware of an xml validator. im  new to android and eclipse :)

Comment: apparently that hasnt fixed the problem and I have used a validator in w3 schools website to try sort the problem but I followed the directions and the error is still there!

Comment: does it I didnt know if it did or not i just googled xml validation and w3 schools came up so i used that. got the problem sorted now! thanks for the help @jahroy

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary closing tags. 
 From `LinearLayout` & `EditText`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/main_title" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:inputType="number" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/check" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:onClick="checkNumbers"
        android:text="@string/button_check" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Your mistake

```
       <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:inputType="number" />       <-- you also closed EditText
</EditText>
```

it has to be

```
      <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

without EditText. Also the same on Your Linear Layout

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" /> <-- closed
```

has to be

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```